# Android IntentService - prevent multiple instances of the same request

Tags: android, android-service

I'm using an IntentService to perform background tasks, such as updating data from a remote server.

In some cases, the same request can be queued multiple times by the user, but I only want to execute it once (there's no point in updating the data from the server twice in a row).

Is there a simple way to do this using an IntentService, or should I just use a standard Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to do this using an IntentService

Unfortunately, no. The `Handler` queue used by the `IntentService` is not visible through the SDK and does not have public methods to let you inspect its contents, anyway.

> should I just use a standard Service?

Probably. You could try to keep your own parallel copy of the work queue, flagging duplicates and ignoring them in your `onHandleIntent()`, but making sure you are always in sync with the real internal queue might get icky.

Comment: The IntentService implementation is pretty simple - I'll just implement my own then.